# Sharing destructors between classes in a common hierarchy

Tags: c++

I read that destructors can't be shared, is this true?

I have a base class with several subclasses and the destructor of
those subclasses does not change. This would result in some duplicated
code.

Is it possible to share the destructor? If not how would I avoid duplicated code in those destructors?

```
Class A{

public:
  ~A() {
    //do something
  }
};

class B: public A{
};
class C: public A{
};
class D: public A{
};
```

Now I want `B`, `C`, and `D` to have the same destructor as `A`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by sharing destructors?

Comment: I'll write an example.

Comment: When a object of a derived class type is destroyed, the derived class version of the destructor will execute, and then afterwards the base class destructor will execute.  Does that help?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean exactly. Do Subclass1 and Subclass2 both act on their data the same way in the destructor? Or do they both not implement a destructor? In the second case you can use a virtual destructor in the base class.

Comment: Probably for a child class to inherit destructors. That's impossible AFAIK.

Comment: @Connor: Virtual destructors have nothing to do with this.  They only affect whether you can use the non-array `delete` operator polymorphically.

Comment: I think `virtual` destructors should at least be mentioned as a warning, because not marking a destructor virtual on a base class is usually a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every class's destructor automatically calls the destructor for all subobjects, including base class subobjects.  So you can share *behavior* of the destructor by putting it in a base or member destructor.  Of course, the derived class still gets its own destructor, but in most cases the compiler-generated one (which does nothing besides the mandatory calls to subobject destructors) is enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't implement a descructor in the inheriting class, a basic one will be generated that will simply call the base class destructor. So it is not shared, but the result is the same.

Comment: And if you *do* implement a destructor, the compiler will still insert calls to the base and member destructors.

Answer (score 1):

From your example the easiest thing to do is:

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual ~A()
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be virtual?

Comment: Why `virtual`?  Why `public:`?

Comment: With a virtual destructor the subclasses destructor will cause the base class to also call its destructor.

It's public so you have access to the destructor. If you don't make it public the object wouldn't be destroyed (if you made it private in some cases it would give a compiler error)

Comment: @ConnorHollis The base class destructor will be called **always**, regardless of whether it's marked `virtual` or not - this should be trivial to verify and should make sense. The `virtual` keyword only helps in one specific case: when derived objects are being `delete`d through a base class pointer.

Comment: I assumed that @MaikKlein wanted to implement some functionality to B,C,D's destructor that would also implement the functionality of A's destructor. 

My mistake honestly, you are both right.